# How to make a login using a database in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

so I'm very new to javafx in intellij idea, i have a problem where I have connected with mySQl database in the database section, but now i can't find anywhere how to select everything from my database without having to use a connection string (because i am already connected with the database)

I have already tried several things like just leaving the connection string out but that wouldn't work, I have searched for the answer for a long time now and can't find it anywhere, I hope someone can help me with this.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class logincontroller extends Application {


    public TextField txtusername;
    public PasswordField txtpassword;
    public Label labeltxt;
    public Button btnLogin;
    String username, password;
    Scene scene1;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public void Login(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, SQLException {
        username = txtusername.getText();
        password = txtpassword.getText();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql;

        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Inlognaam = 1 AND Wachtwoord = 2";
        preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);

        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            labeltxt.setText("Login Failed");
        } else {
            Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));
            Stage secondarystage = new Stage();
            secondarystage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            secondarystage.show();
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        }
        txtusername.setText("");
        txtpassword.setText("");
    }

}
```

this is what i already have at this moment

Comment: I have so no idea what you are asking about. Maybe you try show us a bit of the relevant code. (and of course you need a *connection* to a database in order to use it).

Comment: In intellij you have the option on right sight of the screen to connect with the database, so i already connected it through that so I think I would't need a connection string

Comment: The Data Grip panel on the right side is a JDBC-based client that lets you work with the database simultaneously.  IntelliJ has connected with the database, not your code.  The URL and credentials you gave IntelliJ to connect have to be supplied to your program as well.

Comment: alright, thank you! but how do you create a database connection?

Comment: Dont get me wrong, but you somehow sound like a person claiming "I want to build a skyscraper"; and then you ask "can someone tell me how to hold a shovel to dig the basement?" ... It really sounds like you are massively overburdening yourself. I am sure there are plenty of tutorials that explain to java newbies how to step by step use mysql with java. Read and follow such a tutorial. And forget about all the fancy additional stuff IntelliJ might be able to do. And forget about javafx for the moment. Learn the **basics** first.

Answer (score 0):

In Response to @GhostCat This should help you get started. Make sure however that after using the Connection you close it. Same with PreparedStatments always close them if youre not using them.

````
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connector {
    public Connection con;
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    private final String USERNAME = "username";
    private final String PASSWORD = "password";

    /*
     * Adds DB Connection
     */
    public void add() {
        try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to leave your connection open. You want to connect, select, then close. Please research "Try with Resources" for how to do this properly.

Typically a web server handles sessions so please forgive me for this answer.

What you can do is add a token, ID, secret code, to your Users table that gets sent back to the client. Then in the next controller after your secondary stage loads, you need to do a second connection to the database and a new sql query using the secret code for that user. This way, your database can only return records intended for that specific user.